# Create views dynamically depending on data

Tags: java, android

I have a name, time and experience. I save them in one screen and want to load them on another. I think, creating a view for each would be a good solution. But i'm open to other suggestions. This is the code that I use to save the data.

```
            //Sacando el texto de los editText y guardandolos en sus variables
            d_TaskName = etxt_TaskName.getText().toString();
            d_TaskTime = etxt_TaskTime.getText().toString();
            d_TaskExp = etxt_TaskExp.getText().toString();

            // Guardar nombre de la tarea en TaskName.txt
            try {
                FileOutputStream fou1 = openFileOutput("TaskName.txt", MODE_WORLD_WRITEABLE);
                OutputStreamWriter osw1 = new OutputStreamWriter(fou1);
                try {
                    osw1.write(d_TaskName);
                    osw1.flush();
                    osw1.close();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }

            } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            //Guardar tiempo que dura la tarea en TaskTime.txt
            try {
                FileOutputStream fou2 = openFileOutput("TaskTime.txt", MODE_WORLD_WRITEABLE);
                OutputStreamWriter osw2 = new OutputStreamWriter(fou2);
                try {
                    osw2.write(d_TaskTime);
                    osw2.flush();
                    osw2.close();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }

            } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            // Guardar la experiencia de la tarea en TaskExp.txt
            try {
                FileOutputStream fou3 = openFileOutput("TaskExp.txt", MODE_WORLD_WRITEABLE);
                OutputStreamWriter osw3 = new OutputStreamWriter(fou3);
                try {
                    osw3.write(d_TaskExp);
                    osw3.flush();
                    osw3.close();
                    Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Tarea Guardada", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }

            } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
```

Comment: Another option might be to use `RecyclerView`

Comment: @JohnO'Reilly Oh... I didn't even know that existed and for what I've seen it looks pretty good.

Comment: you could also use `SharedPreferences` to store little pieces of data like you're doing. No need to mess with all this file writer mess.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why don't you use SharedPreferences?
For store your data:

```
SharedPreferences sharedPref = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(getBaseContext());
SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedPref.edit();
editor.putString("TaskName", etxt_TaskName.getText().toString());
editor.apply();
```

For load your data:

```
SharedPreferences sharedPref = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(getBaseContext());
String taskName = sharedPref.getString("TaskName", "");
```